# One raise for multiple events of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, events

I need to log the creation or copied/moving events of files in a folder for which I will be using `FileSystemWatcher`. The issue is that when I paste one file in the folder, `FileSystemWatcher` will raise one Created event. So if I paste `10` files collectively in that folder, 10 events will be raised one by FileSystemWatcher. My requirement is to raise only one event for all 10 files pasted in the folder if they are copied in a simultaneous manner.

Please suggest. Below is the code which I have written with the help of MSDN tutorial.

```
public class FileSystemWatcherUtil2
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        /* creation of a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties */
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\TestFolder";

        /*watch for internal folder changes also*/
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        /* event handlers */
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        /* watching started */
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        /* user should quit the program to stop watching*/
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    /* event handlers definition for changed and renamed */
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to implement a wrapper for the `FileSystemWatcher` which exposes own `CreatedEx` event which would simulate `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event but would raise one time per 10 `Created` event occurences. But keep in mind that we can not be sure that all handler `Created` events are raised in scope of a single copy/move operation. To increase reliability of this approach I would suggest setting a `DirectoryName  NotifyFilters value` so you would observe a single directory, but surely if this fits in your requirements. Perhaps by giving more details about requirements you have we can provide more details so approach would be more reliable, basically the most important thing is hwo to determine common scope of a bulk copy/move operation, so when yu are copying 100 files and int he same time an other copy operation started by OS is in progress you need to filter out it from the former operation you're interested in. So perhaps some common criteria of the files, etc.

1. Implement wrapper for the `FileSystemWatcher`
2. Expose own `CreatedEx` event
3. Subscribe for the `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event and in the handler start a timer for instance for 200ms. If `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event is not raised - raise own `CreatedEx` event, otherwise reset a timer and wait 200ms period.

Period of timer you can determine in the experimental way, just copy multiple files of different size and see which timeout is enough.

If you need to raise `CreatedEx` event one time for exactly 10 simultaneous event occurences - you can introduce simple counter and decrement in `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event handler, and when `counter==0` - raise own `CreatedEx` event.

Comment: I think the only real answer to the OP is that you can't, 10 files create 10 events. It's a FileSystemWatcher, not a PasteWatcher ;)

Comment: @Lazarus : You can use wrapper which would raise own `CreatedEx` one time per 10 internal `Created` event occurences

Comment: Doesn't that still rely on the 10 internal `Created` events occuring within the timeout period of each other (200ms in your example)? Are you actually able to determine that the 10 events are the result of a single paste activity and not perhaps the result of a batch file copying files?

Comment: @Lazarus : right, we can not 100% be sure that this is a single bulk copy/move operation, will add this important point to the answer, thanks

Comment: It can be single paste operation or can be from batch copy. It will depend on user how he is making changes in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for FileSystemWatcher to know if copying was done as one operation because there is no such thing as copying multiple file at once. Windows Explorer makes is look like that by using drag drop but it is essentially multiple copy.

If you want you can write a simple wrapper around FileSystemWatcher that would accept all Create events and if they happen, say 200ms apart, raise a "Multiple Created" event.

Here is a working code to monitor Create events. You can base your wrapper on that to monitor other events if you need and/or expose other properties.

```
public class MyWatcher
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private object listSync = new object();
    private List<FileSystemEventArgs> events = new List<FileSystemEventArgs>();

    public delegate void FileSystemMultipleEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs[] events);
    public FileSystemMultipleEventHandler OnMultipleFilesCreated { get; set; }

    public MyWatcher(string path, NotifyFilters notifyFilters, string filter)
    {
        this.watcher.Path = path;
        this.watcher.Created += FileCreated;
        watcher.Filter = filter;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.timer != null)
        {
            this.timer.Stop();
            lock (this.listSync) this.events.Add(e);
            this.timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            lock (this.listSync) this.events.Add(e);
            this.timer = new Timer(200);
            this.timer.Elapsed += MultipleFilesCreated;
            this.timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void MultipleFilesCreated(object stat, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (OnMultipleFilesCreated != null)
        {
            FileSystemEventArgs[] result;
            lock (this.listSync)
            {
                // make a copy
                result = events.ToArray();
                this.events = new List<FileSystemEventArgs>();
            }
            OnMultipleFilesCreated(this, result);
        }
        this.timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

I am using locking here to make access to list of events thread safe (timer vs FileCreated event). Not using any concurrent collection because they do not have ClearAll() and I would need to lock and remove items one by one or recreate collection with lock anyway.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, going to try your approach as I was also thinking the same.

Comment: This approach is failing when one of the file is very big and takes more time than our default time (say 200ms) in getting copied